# Kendo UI Window modal not working

Tags: kendo-asp.net-mvc

Can anyone help why the modal is not working - background of the window is not greyed out or disabled.  The following is my code:

```
<div>
@(Html.Kendo().Window()
.Name("Wind")
.Title("")
.Content(
        @Html.Partial("New").ToHtmlString()
)
.Width(750)
.Height(500)

.Draggable(true)
.Visible(false)
.Modal(true)
)
```

This is what I have in my _Layout.cshtml:

```
  <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/Site.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/kendo/2014.1.415/kendo.common.min.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/kendo/2014.1.415/kendo.dataviz.min.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/kendo/2014.1.415/kendo.black.min.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/kendo/2014.1.415/kendo.dataviz.black.min.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/kendo/2014.1.415/jquery.min.js")"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/kendo/2014.1.415/kendo.all.min.js")"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/kendo/2014.1.415/kendo.aspnetmvc.min.js")"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/kendo.modernizr.custom.js")"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validationEngine-en.js")" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validationEngine.js")" ></script>
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/validationEngine.jquery.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 2):

Give it a title. That's the only difference I can see between my windows (I have a lot of them and they all work) and your window code.

Comment: Thanks Jasmine.  I added the title but still it did not work.  I open the window on a click event:  function btnTest_click() {
        var wind = $('#Wind');
        wind.data('kendoWindow')
                    .center()
                    .open();
    }

Comment: We do that too, we just don't put it in a var first, but our function is pretty much the same. Check all your jQuery versions and stuff - Kendo just works, if all that stuff is correct. You might want to check the rendered javascript to make sure it's correct, but it almost always is.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on how you open your Kendo window. Here is the example of opening it in the JavaScript function:

```
function openKendoWindow()
{
    var window = $("#Wind");

    window.kendoWindow({
        content: "Hello",
        modal: true
    });
    window.data("kendoWindow").open();
};
```

Notice how I set **modal: true** in the function. Try that.